# Change color buttons for a specific time and then go to normal color SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift

First of all thanks for the help.

What I want to do is a quiz app for iPhones, the main issue that I am having is that when the user selects the answer I want to add a delay of 3 sec and change the color of the buttons showing if the answer was correct or not(red and green), when the delay is finished go back to the original color for the next question. I tried to use sleep() but it didn't change the color only freeze the screen and go to the other question.

```
  func changeButtonColor() {       
       if (questions[qCounter - 1].correct == 1) {

           option1Button.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "LightGreen")
           option2Button.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "LightRed")
           option3Button.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "LightRed")
       }

       if (questions[qCounter - 1].correct == 2) {

           option1Button.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "LightRed")
           option2Button.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "LightGreen")
           option3Button.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "LightRed")
       }

       if (questions[qCounter - 1].correct == 3) {

           option1Button.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "LightRed")
           option2Button.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "LightRed")
           option3Button.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "LightGreen")
       }   

       addDelay()

   }

   func addDelay() {
       sleep(3)
   }
```

When the next question is going to appear is where I have that the buttons change to blue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the others have said, do not use `sleep(_:)` on the main thread. Ever. It locks up the main thread, and the system "Springboard" will terminate your app after a few seconds, thinking it is hung.

You can use `asyncAfter` or a `Timer` to add a delay. The key bit is that you need to provide a block of code to run once the timer fires.

Instead of "addDelay", write code at the bottom of your function that restores your button colors:

```
func changeButtonColor() {   
    //Your code to set button colors based on the correct answer goes here.
    //(I removed it for brevity)

    //When the timer goes off, restore your buttons to their default colors
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 3.0, repeats: false) { (timer) in

           //replace this with whatever code you want to execute after a delay
           option1Button.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightBlue
           option2Button.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightBlue
           option3Button.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightBlue

           //Put the code to display the next question here 
           //so it doesn't happen until after the delay
           self.displayNextQuestion() //Or whatever...
    }
}
```

BTW, a switch statement would be neater than 3 if statements:

```
func changeButtonColor() {       
  switch questions[qCounter - 1].correct {
     case 1:
        //set colors for correct == 1
     case 2:
        //set colors for correct == 2
     case 3:
        //set colors for correct == 3
     default:
        //The compiler will force your switch statement to be exhaustive
        break
  }
}
```

Comment: I just made a minor edit to the timer code, illustrating one way to pause before displaying the next question.

Comment: Thank you a lot, your code works perfectly but I have a bug that makes that the first button disappears after the first interaction, but it is there because if you click where it is supposed to be you can get the answer and also in the delay you can see it.

Comment: If you're want help debugging it you're going to have to post the code. Perhaps create a github repo with your project, then post a new question showing the important parts and also providing a link to the repo.

Comment: Thank you again, just solved the issue, it was a minor coding error that i made.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use sleep function it cause freeze the main thread.

Better if you will use DispatchQueue like this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3.0, execute: {
    // perform your task here...
})
```

In addition, you can also use Timer like below:

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 3.0, repeats: false) { (timer) in
        // perform your task here...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

### First of all: changing on anything UI related should be performed in the main thread. You can reach it with several ways:

**DispatchQueue**

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 0.2) { ... }
```

---

**Timer**

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.2, repeats: false, block: { _ in
        /* Enter here whatever you need to change for the short period of time */
    })
```

`withTimeInterval` - controlled the time the color will be changed

`repeats` = If true, the timer will repeatedly reschedule itself until invalidated. If false, the timer will be invalidated after it fires.